# how to debug jest unit tests on create-react-app?

Tags: debugging, jestjs, create-react-app

I use *create-react-app* and I would like to debug my unit tests

as [Jest documentation says](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html#tests-are-failing-and-you-don-t-know-why), debugging is possible using this command:

```
node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest -i [any other arguments here]
```

unfortunately, it's not working with create-react-app.
I got this error instead:

```
node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest -i
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node
Debugger attached.
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/asafkatz/dev/newmaps/node_modules/.bin/jest'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:590:10)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

**what is the proper way to debug jest unit test on create-react-app?**

Comment: Perhaps you don't have jest installed locally, try 'node --debug-brk --inspect $(which jest) -i'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `jest` along with Chrome DevTools appears to be problematic (see [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1652)).

#### The problem:

You can start the node debugger using the new `V8 Inspector` protocol using the aforementioned command lines (adjust the `jest` path):

```
node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

Meaning:

```
# node params
--debug-brk: start debugger, expose external interface, and break at the first line
--inspect: use the new V8 Inspector protocol in the debugger

# jest params
--runInBand: do not fork (make it debuggable)
```

Then you can use Google Chrome and connect to the given URL or use [this useful extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en) to do it automatically for you.

Unfortunately as of now the `debugger;` calls in test code will not be taken into consideration.

#### The workaround

To work around the problem, for now, you can download a GUI debugger compatible with the plain `V8`protocol such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). In order to use it, you have to start the node debugger without the `--inspect` flag:

```
node --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

Then from VCS you can navigate to the project folder, enter the Debugging section, create the standard debugging configurations, and run the `Attach to Process` config.

Answer (score 8):

I also use VSCode, and in 2018 the above configuration did not work for me. I did finally get it to work, using this config in launch.json:

```
 {
        "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "port":9229,
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/main/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "--inspect-brk",
          "test"
        ],
        "args": [
          "--runInBand",
          "--no-cache",
          "--env=jsdom"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/main",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
      },
```

Note that I have /main after the workspaceRoot value, this may be different for you, since my project is named main. This should be the location of your project root.

In addition, errors **unrelated to my code** were thrown before getting to my tests. In order to fix that, I had to go to the debugger tab under breakpoints, and uncheck "uncaught exceptions" and "module.js".

After I went through these steps I am now able to debug my unit tests, set breakpoints in them, etc, but it still doesn't work as well as I would like. For example it runs an extra command-line in the terminal, and there are other slight weirdnesses. But it does work well enough to get the job done.

Comment: Worked for me!  Also, if you're using Typescript, change "react-scripts" to "react-scripts-ts" in the runtimeExecutable line.

Comment: How did you exactly executed the tests? Did you use debbuger flags or you used vscode breakpoints? I put a bunch of them in a jest file, I press f5 using the configuration you provided, all the tests seems to pass but it doesn't stop on breakpoints

Answer (score 5):

If you're using visual studio code, you can use the following configuration. Hopefully this saves someone a few hours.

**My setup:**

- Un-ejected create-react-app (1.3.1) project
- Node version: **v6.10.3**
- Npm version: 4.6.1

To get this working I also needed to install [jest-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-file) and [jest-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-css) using `npm i --save-dev jest-file jest-css`. These are used as file transformers so that jest doesn't complain about imports for files, for example svg.

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Test with debugger",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 5858,
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--debug-brk",
        "--nolazy"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "args": [
        "--runInBand",
        "--transform={\"^.+\\\\.(js|jsx)$\": \"babel-jest\",\"^.+\\\\.css$\": \"jest-css\",\"^(?!.*\\\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)\": \"jest-file\"}"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Explanation**

--nolazy: fully compile code so that we can use breakpoints correctly

--runInBand: stop Jest from spawning tests in worker processes

--transform: stop errors when importing files such as svg. If you add this to package.json, react-scripts won't let you run `npm test` since it doesn't support overwriting of the transform options.

The following lines need to be added to **package.json** or **.babelrc**

```
"babel": {
  "sourceMaps": "inline",
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

**Explanation**

sourceMaps: This must either be "inline" or "both". If you don't set this, when you debug your tests you'll see transpiled code instead of your source.

presets: `react-app` is the default preset for a create-react-app project. If you don't include this in either package.json or .babelrc you'll get errors because jest won't know how to deal with the jsx.

**Result**
[image]

**If you're not using visual studio code**, you could run the following command and connect to the debugging session using another GUI debugger: `node --debug-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand --config=./jest-config.json`. Just make sure to put the below config in a `jest-config.json` file:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.css$": "jest-css",
  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "jest-file"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The create react app documentation has documentation on how to debug tests.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/debugging-tests/

In summary, all you have to do is add this to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
"test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand --no-cache"
}
```

place a `debugger;` statement in your test and run

```
$ npm run test:debug
```

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` places its node_modules (and therefore jest) in a different location. Try this:

`node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/.bin/jest -i`

If that doesn't work, just do a search in your project's folders for a file called `jest` and update the path.

Comment: For me that initially seems to load correctly in the dev tools but than hangs with "Waiting for the debugger to disconnect..." even though execution is free.

Comment: works but doesn't understand JSX : ` Unexpected token (8:18)
         6 | it("renders without crashing", () => {
         7 |   const div = document.createElement("div");
      >  8 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
           |                   ^
         9 | });`

Comment: @sylvain please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44368963/5362826) below which shows how to resolve this